# SOAP based Webservice Interface with Hasmap as Input Parameter

Tags: web-services, soap, hashmap, cxf

I am trying to build a SOAP based webservice which will have Hashmap as input using Java?

Has anyone tried it before? What kind of problems this might cause?

WHat is the best practice for handling input as Hashmap or List?

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 2):

Found the Solution to have HashMap as input for WebService endpoint.

If you define HashMap directly in input then XSD is not going to show it properly and also WSDL will not b easily understandable.

So, define a input class and add the HasMap as attribute which you planned to be as Input.

```
Class A
{
 HasMap inputData;

 //Add the Getter and Setter
}
```

Have class A as you input to Webserivce Method. Now your WSDL will have HasMap with Key/Vlue pair.

Answer (score 2):

The CXF java_first_jaxws sample:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/distribution/src/main/release/samples/java_first_jaxws/

provides and example on how to "properly" handle Maps (and other interface derived types) with JAX-WS/JAXB.  Basically, you have to create a XmlAdapter that will convert the map into types that JAXB can completely map.  JAXB will then automatically use those adapters at runtime to map to the types it is happy with.   The result it that you have complete control over the resulting schema/wsdl (so you don't have to have the generic "key" and "value" element names) yet also get the convenience of getting to use the Maps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think this is one approach of you want to hadle all the mapping by yourself.Other options I expalined below which is you dfine the HasMap<String,Object> this object will be some concete type which will have actual attributes. This way your WSDL will first show value as type the object you define. In the definition of Object it will show all the attributes.