# Does Apache CXF support HashMap?

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I have created a service method in cxf which take hashmap object as parameter.

I need to call that service method from client.
But I dont know that does cxf really support haspmap value passing...

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to make this work with `CXF`. Take a look at this example source code:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/distribution/src/main/release/samples/java_first_jaxws/

Also take at look at this SO post:

[SOAP based Webservice Interface with Hasmap as Input Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141152/soap-based-webservice-interface-with-hasmap-as-input-parameter)